# How to solve given problem using a* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, path, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

[image]
How to solve this as f(n) is coming same for two paths

Solved using a* by calculating f(n)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.